# WCF service Invalid cast

Tags: vb.net, wcf

So I am working on a ugly legacy windows form project which is written with VB.NET. I am trying to make it use a WCF web service that I wrote before. Everything works fine when I test it locally, however, when I deploy the service to my DEV environment (I have DEV, QA and Production environments) and then change the config file in my win form application to point to the DEV service and then run the application, it gives me a "Invalid Cast Exception". I am totally confused.

The windows form looks like this:
[image]

and basically what the user does is changing the check boxes. Any change happens to the checkbox will trigger function "Security_ColumnChanging()" in the windows form:

```
 Private Sub Security_ColumnChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Data.DataColumnChangeEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim intPersonnel_Id As Integer = m_oDS.Tables("Security").Rows(DataGrid1.CurrentRowIndex)("ID")
        Dim groupId As Integer

        Select Case UCase(e.Column.ColumnName)
            Case "ADMINREPORTS"
                groupId = 1
            Case "BATCH"
                groupId = 2
            Case "SECURITY"
                groupId = 3
            Case "GLOBALRULE"
                groupId = 4
            Case "PROFILES"
                groupId = 5
        End Select

        If e.ProposedValue Then
            dataSource.AddGroupForUser(intPersonnel_Id, groupId)
        Else
            dataSource.DeleteGroupForUser(intPersonnel_Id, groupId)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

You can see there's also a datasource class which will handle all the database inserts and deletes. The two functions in the datasource class are:

```
Public Class SecurityFormDataSource
Public Sub AddGroupForUser(userID As Integer, groupID As Integer)
    Using proxy As Service.AuthenticationService.AuthenticationServiceClient = New Service.AuthenticationService.AuthenticationServiceClient()
        Dim success As Boolean = proxy.AddGroupForUser(userID, groupID, Guid.Empty)
        If success = False Then
            Throw New Exception("Error happened on the service side.")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteGroupForUser(userID As Integer, groupID As Integer)
    Using proxy As Service.AuthenticationService.AuthenticationServiceClient = New Service.AuthenticationService.AuthenticationServiceClient()
        Dim success As Boolean = proxy.DeleteGroupForUser(userID, groupID, Guid.Empty)
        If success = False Then
            Throw New Exception("Error happened on the service side.")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

And the datasource class finally calls functions in the "Authentication service" to actually insert or delete the database records. When I run the service on my local machine, everything works perfectly, but after I deploy the service to any of my environments and then test the windows form again, I have this error:
[image]

And the stack trace is:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridBoolColumn.Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle   bounds, CurrencyManager source, Int32 rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, Boolean alignToRight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridRelationshipRow.PaintCellContents(Graphics g, Rectangle cellBounds, DataGridColumnStyle column, Brush backBr, Brush foreBrush, Boolean alignToRight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridRow.PaintData(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, Int32 firstVisibleColumn, Int32 columnCount, Boolean alignToRight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridRelationshipRow.Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, Rectangle trueRowBounds, Int32 firstVisibleColumn, Int32 numVisibleColumns, Boolean alignToRight)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.PaintRows(Graphics g, Rectangle& boundingRect)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.PaintGrid(Graphics g, Rectangle gridBounds)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: This is VB.NET, not C#...

Comment: Are you deploying the same flavor that you were testing locally (retail/debug)?

Comment: @RufusL Yeah, I didn't deploy it manually, I used the Microsoft Release Management Studio, so the services in different environments will always be the same

Comment: Try to enable stopping on first-chance exception (your `InvalidCastException`) - it will break exactly at place where it fails to cast.